# My form is not correctly taking the route

Tags: node.js, express

I have this weird issue and it seems that I can't resolve it.
Whenever I submit my form, it goes to a "double route".

This is my html form.

```html
<form action="eveniment/<%=eveniment._id%>" method="POST" id="modificaeveniment">
  <input type="text" placeholder="titlu eveniment" name="titlu" value="<%= eveniment.name %>">
  <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is the route:

```
app.post("/eveniment/:id", function(req, res){ res.send("post route"); }
```

And I always get the error:
Cannot POST /eveniment/5f1740204a5a2206cc02b5af/eveniment/5f1740204a5a2206cc02b5af

It looks like somehow it doubles the route.

Comment: Could you add more information about your error, I think the error could be, 404-NotFound,  because it is probably that you post on the endpoint: /eveniment with the body: { ”id”:”value”}

Comment: I put this in a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7t1pevn2/4/

Comment: It's just that instead of post eveniment/id, my website goes to post eveniment/id/eveniment/id

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `/` at `action="eveniment/<%=eveniment._id%>"`

````
<form action="/eveniment/<%=eveniment._id%>" method="POST" id="modificaeveniment">
  <input type="text" placeholder="titlu eveniment" name="titlu" value="<%= eveniment.name %>">
  <button class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
</form>```
````